# How to insert struct into vector that lives inside the HashMap?

Tags: rust

I have the struct that looks like:

```rust
pub struct MonthlyProjection {
    pub sequence: u32,
    pub total_deposit: f64,
}
```

I have this function which takes reference of the vector that contains these structs:

```rust
fn generate_projections(simulation_results: &Vec<MonthlySimulationResult>)
```

Inside this function, I have to group the `MonthlyProject` structs by their sequences, and do some calculation with it.

So here is my logic:

1. Create mutable `HashMap<u32, Vec<MonthlySimulationResult>>`, called `result_map`
2. For loop over the `simulation_results` vector
3. If the `result_map` already has the vector for the given sequence number, then insert the item into that existing vector, then update the `result_map`
4. If the `result_map` does not have the existing vector for the given sequence number, then create new vector, insert the struct, and update the `result_map`

How would you do this?

Comment: Have a look at the `entry` method on `HashMap`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind pulling in the extra dependency, maybe look at itertools:

https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by

Otherwise, you can write a for-loop using the `entry` API:

```rust
let mut result_map: HashMap<u32, Vec<_>> = HashMap::new();
for projection in simulation_results {
    result_map.entry(projection.sequence).or_default().push(projection);
}
result_map
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=187c1028e00eec4bd836b299b57b74bb).)

Note that you specified a `MonthlyProjection` type but then you specified the function header and its return type with `MonthlySimulationResult`, so not clear what's going on there. Also, you pass in a reference to the `Vec<MonthlyProjection>` but return a transitively owned `MonthlySimulationResult`, so you need to do something there.